# Scaling sound Java

Tags: java, audio, javasound

I'm trying to perform a linear scaling of an Audio Input, with the same scaling on each channel.

The overall effect is that the Input Stream gradually decreases in amplitude until it is silent. So my first sample will stay the same and my last sample will be 0 in terms of amplitude. I was wondering how you implement this.

So far, this is what I have of the scaling code and was wondering whether you still need to scale the sample so that it lies between the  16 digit two's complement range.

```
 for (int i=0; i<data.length; ++i){ // data[i] is sample in intger form
        data[i] = (int) (data[i]*(something/something)); 
 }
```

It'd be helpful if scaling to a specific factor could be explained?

Thanks!

Comment: What is your actual question? If you did the scaling correctly, and you're only reducing amplitude, it will automatically be in 16-bit range. However your code is incorrect - why do you need to multiple the sample with the max value - that makes it 32 bit range and much louder? And what happens if you divide by zero in the first iteration of your loop? Did you even run the code?

Comment: @erwin bolwidt my question is how do you scale linearly to 0. Would I just divide each sample by 0?

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming that you are working with short values for your audio data (e.g., [-32768..32767]) and the conversion to and from bytes is handled elsewhere.

In your fraction, "something/something", the numerator would range from a value equal to the denominator down to zero while the denominator remains a fixed value.

Example, if you are breaking the volume range into 128 steps, the loudest volume would be 128/128, the quietest volume would be 0/128.

To avoid division, you can precalculate the factor equal to 1/128, and multiply it by a value within the range [0..128] inclusive.

Then you would have "something * precalculatedFactor" which might run a tiny bit faster.

But, there are problems that come up with linear volume scaling. Actual perceived volume does not track linearly. Thus, a volume interval of X may barely create a volume difference at the high end, but will be so large as to cause a discontinuity and click at the low end.

I think people often use an exponential function to better map volume to a linear input. There are disagreements as to which is best. But suppose your volume dial goes from [0..1]. If you cube the value before applying it, for example, an input of 0.5 in an attempt to create 1/2 the loudness becomes (0.5 * 0.5 * 0.5) => 0.125, this will be closer to 1/2 loudness than 0.5.

Thus, "something * something * something * precalculatedFactorCubed" might work better.

Comment: The channels alternate left and right. You would apply the same factors and calculation to each of the two values.